# Where Are JanusGraph's Vertexes In Cassandra?

Tags: gremlin, cassandra-3.0, janusgraph, cqlsh, java-17

Where does [Apache Cassandra](https://docs.janusgraph.org/storage-backend/cassandra/) put its [JanusGraph Vertexes](https://docs.janusgraph.org/master/interactions/transactions/)?

When I look for them I can't find them. I've tried using `cqlsh` but I'm new to [`CQL` (Cassandra Query Language)](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/cql/) and Cassandra in-general. So please forgive my lack of knowledge and unskillful writing. I'm still working on learning the [Gremlin query language](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/gremlin.html) for JanusGraph's Gremlin.

## Reproduction

### Steps

1. Create-and-Startup a [Cassandra [Docker container]](https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra)

   ```bash
   docker run --name jg-cassandra -d -e CASSANDRA_START_RPC=true -p 9160:9160 -p 9042:9042 -p 7199:7199 -p 7001:7001 -p 7000:7000 cassandra:3.11
   ```
2. Create-and-Run this Java + Maven Project (code below)
3. Results

   1. Expected: Something like OrientDB or Neo4j to have a table for vertexes to read from
   2. Actually: No such name like `V` or `vertex` found

### Logs

#### `Cassandra [Docker container] Terminal`

```bash
cqlsh> desc keyspaces;

system_schema  system      system_distributed
system_auth    janusgraph  system_traces     

cqlsh> use janusgraph;

cqlsh:janusgraph> desc tables

edgestore_lock_  graphindex_lock_         janusgraph_ids   
txlog            systemlog                graphindex       
edgestore        system_properties_lock_  system_properties
```

#### `Log4j2 STOUT Logs`

```json
2023-05-09 11:01:53,970 [INFO] [c.d.o.d.i.c.ContactPoints.main] ::   Contact point localhost:9042 resolves to multiple addresses, will use them all ([localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1])
2023-05-09 11:01:54,072 [INFO] [c.d.o.d.i.c.DefaultMavenCoordinates.main] ::     DataStax Java driver for Apache Cassandra(R) (com.datastax.oss:java-driver-core) version 4.15.0
2023-05-09 11:01:54,652 [INFO] [c.d.o.d.i.c.t.Clock.JanusGraph Session-admin-0] ::   Using native clock for microsecond precision
2023-05-09 11:01:54,967 [WARN] [c.d.o.d.i.c.l.h.OptionalLocalDcHelper.JanusGraph Session-admin-0] ::     [JanusGraph Session|default] You specified datacenter1 as the local DC, but some contact points are from a different DC: Node(endPoint=localhost/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=7b9f753a)=null; please provide the correct local DC, or check your contact points
2023-05-09 11:01:55,209 [INFO] [o.j.g.i.UniqueInstanceIdRetriever.main] ::   Generated unique-instance-id=c0a8563c1700-rmt-lap-win201
2023-05-09 11:01:55,231 [INFO] [c.d.o.d.i.c.ContactPoints.main] ::   Contact point localhost:9042 resolves to multiple addresses, will use them all ([localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1])
2023-05-09 11:01:55,265 [INFO] [c.d.o.d.i.c.t.Clock.JanusGraph Session-admin-0] ::   Using native clock for microsecond precision
2023-05-09 11:01:55,322 [WARN] [c.d.o.d.i.c.l.h.OptionalLocalDcHelper.JanusGraph Session-admin-0] ::     [JanusGraph Session|default] You specified datacenter1 as the local DC, but some contact points are from a different DC: Node(endPoint=localhost/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=1dc6cab9)=null; please provide the correct local DC, or check your contact points
2023-05-09 11:01:55,341 [INFO] [o.j.d.c.ExecutorServiceBuilder.main] ::  Initiated fixed thread pool of size 40
2023-05-09 11:01:55,447 [INFO] [o.j.g.d.StandardJanusGraph.main] ::  Gremlin script evaluation is disabled
2023-05-09 11:01:55,473 [INFO] [o.j.d.l.k.KCVSLog.main] ::   Loaded unidentified ReadMarker start time 2023-05-09T16:01:55.473310Z into org.janusgraph.diskstorage.log.kcvs.KCVSLog$MessagePuller@ff23ae7

Process finished with exit code 0
```

### Code

#### `Main.java` simplified

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JanusGraph janusGraph = JanusGraphFactory.build().set("storage.backend", "cql").set("storage.hostname", "localhost:9042").open();
        JanusGraphManagement janusGraphManagement = janusGraph.openManagement();
        PropertyKey propertyKey = janusGraphManagement.getOrCreatePropertyKey("_id");
        janusGraphManagement.commit();
        JanusGraphVertex janusGraphVertex = janusGraph.addVertex();
        janusGraphVertex.property("test","test");
        janusGraph.tx().commit();
        janusGraphVertex = janusGraph.addVertex();
        janusGraphVertex.property("test","test2");
        janusGraph.tx().commit();
        janusGraph.close();
    }
}
```

#### `pom.xml` snippet

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j2-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.janusgraph</groupId>
            <artifactId>janusgraph-cql</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-20230504-014643.988c094</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

#### `log4j2.xml` focused

```xml
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d [%p] [%c{1.}.%t] ::&#x09; %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

### Resources

1. [Maven 3.8.1](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi)
2. [Java 11.0.19 (corretto-11)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-11-ug/downloads-list.html)
3. [JanusGraph 1.0.0-20230504-014643.988c094](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/releases/tag/v1.0.0-rc2)
4. [Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10%20)
5. [Docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra)
6. [Cassandra:latest [container]](https://docs.janusgraph.org/storage-backend/cassandra/)
7. [ICIJ Offshore Dataleaks](https://github.com/ICIJ/offshoreleaks-data-packages/blob/eabbabfeaf1983c2b83c11125802fcdeda92d9ac/data/icij-offshoreleaks-44.dump)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed, JanusGraph creates several tables when it starts up. All the primary graph data is stored as wide rows in the `edgestore` table. However, these tables are largely opaque blobs and you will not be able to query them meaningfully from CQL.

The way that the `edgestore` table is constructed is discussed [here](https://docs.janusgraph.org/advanced-topics/data-model/)

Comment: How do you meaningfully query them instead then? Like return a sample size of 1000 Vertexes?

Comment: Using Gremlin queries is really the only way. You can either connect using a Gremlin Server or just connect directly to Janus/Cassandra from something like the Gremlin Console and run queries like `g.V().limit(10)` or `g.V().sample(100)` or even `g.V().groupCount().by(label())` . You will want to make sure full index scans are enabled. You will know if they are not as those queries will give a warning.

Comment: How do you Gremlin-Console connect to a JanusGraph-Cassandra? 
I've tried all `TCP-Ports: [7000, 7001, 7199, 9042, 9160]` but none are successful with Gremlin-Console.

Comment: Are you trying to connect directly from the Console, or via a Gremlin Server? If it's a direct connection, something as simple as `gremlin> graph = JanusGraphFactory.open('conf/janusgraph-cql.properties')` is usually all you need. I believe CQL normally listens on 9042. Is your Docker container exposing that port?

Comment: I'm trying to connect directly from the Gremlin-Console.

Comment: So the above should work. It's important to make sure that you use the Gremlin Console that comes with JanusGraph and not the one from the TinkerPop website. The Janus one comes pre-configured to work with a JanusGraph and has all the properties files needed.

Comment: I think it worked? `gremlin> graph = JanusGraphFactory.open('conf/janusgraph-cql.properties') 
... 12:52:46 INFO  org.janusgraph.diskstorage.log.kcvs.KCVSLog$MessagePuller.initializeTimepoint - Loaded unidentified ReadMarker start time 2023-05-18T17:52:46.348244Z into org.janusgraph.diskstorage.log.kcvs.KCVSLog$MessagePuller@34d3409d
==>standardjanusgraph[cql:[127.0.0.1]]`

Comment: Do I still need to set my own `g.V()`? `gremlin> g.V().limit(10)
No such property: g for class: groovysh_evaluate`

Comment: yes, just do `g = graph.traversal()` and see if that works.

Comment: Worked great - Thanks [Kelvin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5442034/kelvin-lawrence)!  

`gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[standardjanusgraph[cql:[127.0.0.1]], standard]
gremlin> g.V().limit(1) 
13:01:08 WARN  org.janusgraph.graphdb.transaction.StandardJanusGraphTx$3.execute - Query requires iterating over all vertices [[]]. For better performance, use indexes
==>v[754491408]`

Comment: How do I change its ports? I've got multiple tests running, so I need change this to 30000 offset.